# Which foods or drinks are reusable?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

A while back I found the [Tasty Talador Lunch](http://www.wowhead.com/item=116120/tasty-talador-lunch), which is a reusable food, but it only works in Talador.  Then recently I found [Ba'ruun's Bountiful Bloom](http://www.wowhead.com/item=113540/baruuns-bountiful-bloom) which does the same thing, but works anywhere.

Is there a list somewhere of all food/drink that are reusable?

Comment: I haven't heared about any other reusables. But for example a mage can make a table where you can stock up on food. And a lvl 3 herbfarm will have a tree that drops free buff food (75 stat), but the stat it boosts is dependent on what kind of fruit the tree dropped that day.

Comment: Bloom does not work anywhere, e.g. it does not work in Raid Instances. Besides those items, there is no real reusable food in WoW.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Try it again. Won't work. I raid nhc, hc and myth and it does not work there. No idea about LFR.
'

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness: I tried Bloom earlier on a Normal raid and it worked.  I am using it on a Heroic as I type this.

Comment: I found another one: http://www.wowhead.com/item=118935/ever-blooming-frond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, all reusable food items are now classified as Toys in Legion as opposed to standard items.

At present, the following food items are reusable:

- [Ba'ruun's Bountiful Bloom](http://www.wowhead.com/item=113540/baruuns-bountiful-bloom)

  - Only works on Draenor
  - 5 minute cooldown
- [Tasty Talador Lunch](http://www.wowhead.com/item=116120/tasty-talador-lunch)

  - Works everywhere as of Legion
  - 15 minute cooldown
- [Bottomless Stygana Mushroom Brew](http://www.wowhead.com/item=128223/bottomless-stygana-mushroom-brew)

  - Only works outdoors on Draenor
  - 20 minute cooldown
- [The "Devilsaur" Lunchbox](http://www.wowhead.com/item=130151/the-devilsaur-lunchbox)

  - Only works on the Broken Isles

    - Notably does **not** work on Argus
  - 15 minute cooldown

Comment: I didn't include Ever Blooming Frond as it's not really a food item even though it does heal.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is usually no clear ingame indicator to which consumables are reusable and which aren't, however if it is reusable it's **almost guaranteed that it has a cooldown**, otherwise you'd be able to use it constantly and never needing to use expendable ones (unless it's significantly less effective).